# sliding windows shifting 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, window

Here I am using rolling_window2D, the problem that I am facing is shifting more than one index:

```
 def rollingwindow2D(a,y):
     h= a[np.arange(a.shape[0]-y+2)[:,None] + np.arange(y-1)]
     return h
```

**The output is:**

```
[1 2 3]  [4 5 6]  [7 8 9]    [10 11 12] [13 14 15]

[4 5 6]   [7 8 9]   [10 11 12]   [13 14 15]   [16 17 18]

[7 8 9]   [10 11 12]   [13 14 15]   [16,17,18]   [19 20 21]
```

**The output that I want:**

```
[1 2 3]   [4 5 6]   [7 8 9]   [10 11 12]   [13 14 15]

[10 11 12]   [13 14 15]   [16 17 18]   [19 20 21]   [22 23 24]

[19 20 21]   [22 23 24]   [25 26 27]   [28 29 30]   [31 32 33]
```

Comment: Could you share a and y ?

Comment: p = rollingwindow2D(finalarray,4)

Comment: finalarray=[ -0.17829895  -9.78656006  -0.13970947]
 [ -0.31468201  -9.84637451  -0.95805359]
 [  0.01791382  -9.47070312  -0.29524231]
 [ -0.13841248  -9.81884766   0.63874817]
 [  0.20814514  -9.40011597   0.91912842]
 [ -0.5970459   -9.28405762   1.07585144]
 [ -0.02874756  -9.53530884   0.97535706]
 [  0.27275085  -9.47549438   1.07943726]
 [ -0.22496033  -9.41687012   1.1081543 ]
 [  0.15071106  -9.75306702   0.6786499 ]